# Short exact sequence with four terms

Tags: homological-algebra

We want to build an exact sequence
$$
0 \longrightarrow A \longrightarrow B \longrightarrow C \longrightarrow D \longrightarrow 0
$$
such that $A \oplus C \cong B \oplus D$ and other in which that property does not hold.

Is it possible to obtain this with all modules not being null? I am trying to extend the idea of inclusion and projection with the direct sum in the middle term but doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$R$ a ring, take $A = R$, $B = R \oplus R$, $C = R \oplus R$ and $D = R$. We name our morphism in order $\alpha$, $\beta$, $\gamma$.
Take
$$\alpha = 1_R \oplus 0$$
$$\beta \circ(1_R\oplus 0) = 0 \oplus 0 , \, \beta \circ(0\oplus 1_R) = 1_R \oplus 0$$
$$\gamma \circ (1_R \oplus 0) = 0 , \, \gamma\circ(0 \oplus 1_R) = 1_R$$

For the non-split version, take $A = \mathbb{Z}$, $B = \mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z}$, $C = \mathbb{Z}$ and $D = \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$
And
$$\alpha(1) = 1\oplus 0$$
$$\beta(1\oplus 0) = 0 , \, \beta(0\oplus 1) = 2 $$
$$\gamma(1) = 1$$

You can easily extend the length of your sequence for both examples

Comment: Yes, thanks. I think it should be $\alpha(n) = (n, 0)$ in both cases instead of $\gamma$. Also, nice remark!

Comment: Yes a small typo :)

Comment: And $\gamma(n, m) = m$ in the first example :)

Comment: Yes, also I used $1_R$ as the identity function on $R$ to avoid imposing $R$ unitary :)

Comment: Beware: you can’t give general counterexamples since for some rings like fields, you only have split sequences!